# Error in inserting sql when using multiple where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have been getting the error *Unknown column 'meta_key' in 'where clause'*

```
$sql_select = "SELECT degree_name,specialisation
    FROM eduaction_record WHERE (meta_key = 'user_id' AND meta_value = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."') 
    AND (meta_key = 'degree_name' AND meta_value = '$contentToSaveDegreeName')
    AND (meta_key = 'specialisation' AND meta_value = '$contentToSaveAreaOfSpecialisationDegree')
    ";
```

And this is my table structure

```
SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `degree_name`, `specialisation`, `institute`, `date_of_passing` FROM `eduaction_record` WHERE 1
```

Help me find the right syntax.

Comment: error message is pretty clear. check ( and post ) your table definition for column `meta_key`

Comment: @amdixon please elaborate :)

Comment: Please check whether `meta_key` is present in your `eduaction_record` table definition or not

Comment: Is there a column named `meta_key` inside of the tables you are selecting from? Just go through your table structures to ascertain this.

Comment: @OmniPotens it isn't there. I dont know the proper syntax :(

Comment: There is no column specified as`meta_key` in you select query.

Comment: Where did you get the SELECT statement from?

Comment: execute `show create table eduaction_record` to see the table definition

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Can you help me with the syntax for my table?

Comment: @Niranjan has the right syntax in his answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query(copy pasted form somewhere) is totally wrong.

You have more errors.

the column `meta_key` is not in `eduaction_record` table. Check the table and update the column name.

- Next error will be

  `Unknown column 'meta_value' in 'where clause'`

  You don't even have `meta_value` in the structure you have provided.

This should be your query.

```
$sql_select = "SELECT degree_name,specialisation
FROM eduaction_record WHERE (user_id = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}') 
AND (degree_name = '$contentToSaveDegreeName')
AND (specialisation = '$contentToSaveAreaOfSpecialisationDegree')";
```

**EDIT**

```
function degree_exists($contentToSaveDegreeName, $contentToSaveAreaOfSpecialisationDegree)‌ {
    global $msg, $dbh1;
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $sql_select = "SELECT degree_name,specialisation FROM eduaction_record "
            . "WHERE user_id = '$user_id' "
            . "AND degree_name = '$contentToSaveDegreeName' "
            . "AND specialisation = '$contentToSaveAreaOfSpecialisationDegree'";
    $stmt = $dbh1->query($sql_select);
}
```

Comment: Dhanyavaad. But am still facing problem with my query. It says:Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Comment: I am new to this. So please guide me through this process :)

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Bachelor Of Technology,IIT - Kanpur,2015-11,Aerospace)' at line 2

Comment: What are the values of `$contentToSaveDegreeName` and `$contentToSaveAreaOfSpecialisationDegree`

Comment: umm both are type text

Comment: Do you see the bracket at the end of Aerospace ??thats the error i guess

Comment: $contentToSaveDegreeName = filter_var($_POST["degree_name"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $contentToSaveDegreeSchool = filter_var($_POST["degree_school"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $contentToSaveAreaOfSpecialisationDegree = filter_var($_POST["area_of_specialisation_degree"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $contentToSaveDateOfSchoolPassed = filter_var($_POST["date_of_school_passed"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

Comment: that was a yo index-finger and the pinky raised and multmusec is thank you in romanian ;)

Comment: the previous one itself was correct. It was my php file causing problem :|. Fixed it through your help. Thanks again and do excuse me for making you go through the query again and again :)

Answer (score 1):

The column `meta_key` does not exist in that specific table you are searching in.